# Java - JDBC MySQL driver not found Netbeans Win8

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I'm trying to develop an Java Application but the problem I came across is that when I'm trying to connect to the database when running the application I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. I've spent over two days figuring it out and I could not solve the problem. I am on Win 8.1 with Netbeans IDE 7.1.

I have also tried re-creating the application and at the beggining everything worked fine until I made it Object Oriented again.

So here is my MySQLConnect.java:

```
   package calylibrary;

   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

    public class MySQLConnect {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection connectDb()
    {
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
    String dbUser = "root";
    String dbPassword = "";

    try
    {
        Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser,       dbPassword);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MySQLConnect to MySQLConnect Database Established.");
        return conn;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }

    }

    }
```

I run it from a main class like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    MySQLConnect.connectDb();

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

The complete error message I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at calylibrary.MySQLConnect.connectDb(MySQLConnect.java:19)
at calylibrary.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:483)
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load JDBC MySQL driver:

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);
    return conn;
}
```

So it's "com" not "con". :)

Comment: Sorry, I have added the wrong code, it has it, I have updated my question with correct code for MySQLConnect.java and error output.

Comment: I will, time's not up on that yet but I will. Thank you!